# Tidal - How to get output of web services job on to hard disk? Please let me know

Tags: web-services, tidal-scheduler

Tidal - How to get output of web services job on to hard disk? I a trying to output the results of web services job on to hard disk. Please let me know who I can achieve this using Tidal.

Answer (score 0):

Create a second job that depends on the web service job.  In this second job, use the "output" command from the Tidal command line interface to save the output of the previous job to a file.  It would look something like this:

```
command: /path/to/tidal/sacmd
parameters:
-i <JobID..1234> -o /path/to/output/file.out
```

For the job id parameter, you select the predecessor web service job and the JobID reference to the predecessor gets filled in as above.

sacmd may be called tescmd depending on the OS and the version of Tidal you are using.